# Array to string conversion error in yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

```
$brand = Brand::find()->all();
```

It shows

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Array to string conversion

Comment: Can you please add some more information about the error? Maybe there's a bug in your Brand model that gets evaluated in the find() method first.

Comment: but when i   var_dump(Brand::find()->all())    it displays results

Comment: is $brand a string? Do you use strong typing features of PHP7? Maybe the bug is in the line before (termination missing)?

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: What was the bug? please share it...

Comment: it was inside <?= ?> tht is iwas trying to echo an array ,that was the error